# Нужно перевести код с python на java

Tags: python, java

форумчане! Требуется простой код на python перевести на java. Моих знаний не хватает, к сожалению..

```
from functools import reduce
groups = [1,3]
rdc = reduce(lambda acc, val: acc + 2 ** val, groups, 0)
pgm = rdc.to_bytes(16, byteorder='little', signed=False)
print(pgm.hex()[:16])
```

Был такой вариант, но результаты выполнения reduce не соответствуют...

```
Stream<Integer> numbersStream = Stream.of(1, 3);
Integer result = numbersStream.reduce(0, (x, y) -> (int) pow(x + 2, y));
System.out.println(result);
```

Приведу немного результатов при разных входных данных:

```
[1,3] - 0a00000000000000 
[1] - 0200000000000000
[1, 5] - 2200000000000000
```

Comment: Чему равно `1 + 2 ** 2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Наверное, кривовато выглядит, но работает

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import static java.lang.Math.pow;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.nio.*;

public class Main
{
    
    private static void toHEX(int[] numbers){
        Stream<Long> numbersStream = Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToObj(id -> new Long(id));
        
        long result = numbersStream.reduce(0L, (x, y) -> (long)(x + pow(2,y)));

        // подсмотрено тут https://stackoverflow.com/a/34807563/15035314
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        buffer.asLongBuffer().put(result);
        buffer.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        long flipped = buffer.asLongBuffer().get();
        
        System.out.println("hex little endian: " + String.format("%016x", flipped));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.toHEX(new int[]{1,3});
        Main.toHEX(new int[]{1});
        Main.toHEX(new int[]{1,5});
    }
    
}
```

```
hex little endian: 0a00000000000000
hex little endian: 0200000000000000
hex little endian: 2200000000000000
```

Comment: А можно как-то наоборот потом привести? То есть на вход даем 0a00000000000000, получаем {1,3} ?